# Windows 7 running on Macbook pro not resuming after hibernate

Tags: windows-7, ssd, boot-camp, hibernate

I have a mid 2010 Macbook Pro 13" on which I was running Windows 7 32 bit perfectly fine. Recently I upgraded the memory to 8 GB and put in a Samsung 840 256 GB SSD into the DVD drive bay. I cloned and restored the Lion os onto the new ssd. I had removed the Windows partition before cloning as I wanted to setup Windows 7 64 bit afresh on the new disk.

Lion works perfectly fine. Installation of Windows 64 bit went through fine. Installed the latest Bootcamp drivers I could find. So in summary everything works fine except hibernate.

When I hibernate the machine the screen goes blank and I assume it has hibernated. When I power on the machine again it will say that the machine was improperly shut down and it will give me the screen that asks me whether I want to start Windows in Safe more or normally. If I start it normally, it doesn't resume the hibernated session (obviously) and just starts up with a brand new session.

I have tried this more than 10 times. Fails each time. Anyone else has this problem? In hindsight maybe I should have put the SSD into the original hard disk bay (not sure if that would change anything). Maybe it has something to do with with the Bootcamp drivers not supporting AHCI on windows.

and oh yeah.... sleep works.

Anyone else with this problem? Anything I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Macbook Pro 13 late 2011 with Mountain Lion and Windows 7 64 bit on a 240GB Kingston SSD disc.

I intended to connect the SSD disc to the DVD drive connnector and a non-standard height 14.5mm harddisc to the original harddisc connector.

When the SSD disc is connected to the harddisc connector ( dvd connected or disconnected ) everything is fine.

When the SSD disc is connected to the DVD connector ( 2'nd disc connected or disconnected ) everything is fine except that hibernation does not work. In my case Windows crashed every time with a BSOD saying INTERNAL_POWER_FAILURE when trying to hibernate. I read that enlarging the hibernation file might solve the problem but it does not.

With the SSD connected to the harddisc connector and a ( smaller 9.5mm ) harddisc connected to the DVD drive connector then everything works.

I gave up and resorted to the SSD connected to the harddisc connector and a standard 1TB 9.5mm disc connected to the DVD drive connector ( using a craddle ).

Regards

Comment: Looks like something I could try. I dual boot with Windows 7. Do you know if interchanging the disk positions will screw up the operating systems? Will I have to re install everything?